# quick edit mode direction in SharePoint list view by jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, jquery, list-view, jquery-ui

I need change direction of quick edit mode in SharePoint list view, try in change in jQuery does not apply because of template JavaScript of share point that occur after clicking for editing fields.
it missed the base left and displace the page and move editing input element to another place in page.
Please help

Comment: I only access to web part script in role of designer and owner of list.

Comment: is there any idea?